# How can I solve this weird error while using map in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, stl, c++17

I'm getting stuck in a weird infinite loop while using map in c++.
The first code works good and outputs numbers.

The test cases are:

5 2

1 2 3 4 5

```
long long N, K, count = 0;
cin>>N>>K;
long long l;
map<long long, long long> mp;

for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
    cin>>l;
    ++mp[l];
}


for(auto a:mp){
    cout<<a.first + K<<" "<<a.first - K;
}
```

For the next code I'm getting stuck into an infinite loop, for the same test case, don't know why?

```
long long N, K, count = 0;
cin>>N>>K;
long long l;
map<long long, long long> mp;

for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
    cin>>l;
    ++mp[l];
}

for(auto a:mp){
    cout<<mp[a.first + K]<<" "<<mp[a.first - K];
}
```

The last code keeps on printing 0 till an infinite loop. Any idea why?

Comment: The problem is that if the key is not found inside the map, a key-value pair will automatically be created and inserted into the map and so you're changing the `std::map` while iterating it. You can use `std::map::at` to see that some keys whose values you're looking for are not in the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **problem** is that if the key is not found inside the map, a key-value pair will automatically be created and inserted into the map and so you're changing the size of the `map` while iterating it leading to **undefined behavior**.

Undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output.  But **never rely** on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

You can use `std::map::at` member function which will throw `std::out_of_range` exception when the key is not already inside the map, to confirm that some keys whose corresponding value you're looking for are not inside the `map`.

> How can I solve this weird error while using map

To **solve** this make sure, that you don't change the size of the `map` while iterating it.

Answer (score 0):

`a.first + K` might not be a exist key in the map and when you use `mp[a.first + K]`, it might insert a new key and there is no rules for how the iterator will become.

> How can I solve this weird error while using map in c++

Check the existence before use it.